# QoS - Difference between MQC and HQF

Tags: qos

I understand that the older versions of Cisco IOS implemented the MCQ and the newer one's implement HQF. Could some explain what is the difference between MQC and HQF?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MQC** (Modular QoS CLI) is the CLI structure that allows you to enable QoS features in Cisco routers (see the [manual](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/qos/configuration/guide/qcfmdcli.html)). It uses the following three steps to configure QoS:

1. Define a traffic class with the class-map command.
2. Create a traffic policy by associating the traffic class with one or more QoS features (using the policy-map command).
3. Attach the traffic policy to the interface with the service-policy command.

**HQC** (Hierarchical Queuing Framework) is an evolution of MQC that is introduced in IOS 12.4(20)T, that adds the following functionality (from the [white paper](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/ios-nx-os-software/quality-of-service-qos/white_paper_c11-481499.html)):

- The ability to provide multiple levels of packet scheduling
- The ability to support integrated class-based shaping and queuing
- The ability to apply fair queuing and drop policies on a per-class basis